# Reminder notification

Tags: android

This is the code for call reminder at particular date and time. The problem is that the reminder notification is displayed as soon as user hits Submit button.Thats may be bcoz the notification is displayed at System's time(emulator or phone time) rather than the time and date selected by user.There might be problem in placement of "timePicked = c.getTimeInMillis();" or problem in onDateSet() or onTimeSet() method..Any suggestions?This is very important for me for interview purpose.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public static EditText text;
    public static EditText text2;
    //public static int hour,minute,month,day,year;
public static long timePicked = -1;

static Calendar c;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        text2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        final Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
        c= new GregorianCalendar();

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                timePicked = c.getTimeInMillis();
                Log.d("test", "timePicked: " + timePicked);
                Log.d("test", "current: " + System.currentTimeMillis() );
                if (timePicked != -1) {
                    MyBroadcastReceiver alarm = new MyBroadcastReceiver();
                    if(alarm != null) alarm.setOnetimeTimer(MainActivity.this,timePicked);

                    btn.setText("ALARM SET");
                    Log.d("test", "ALARM SET!!!");
                } else {
                    //warn the user for ALARM not set?
                    Log.w("test", "ALARM not SET!!!");
                }
            }
        });

    }






public static class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Use the current time as the default values for the picker
//final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

// Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
}
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    // Do something with the time chosen by the user
         //Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
            c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
            c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);

         //timePicked = c.getTimeInMillis();
           // Log.d("test", "timePicked: " + timePicked);
            //Log.d("test", "current: " + System.currentTimeMillis() );
    }

}

public void showTimePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(),"timePicker");
}
public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Use the current date as the default date in the picker
//final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
//long millis=c.getTimeInMillis(); 
// Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
}

public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
// Do something with the date chosen by the user
    //Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
    c.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    c.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, month);
    //timePicked = c.getTimeInMillis();
    //Log.d("test", "timePicked: " + timePicked);
    //Log.d("test", "current: " + System.currentTimeMillis() );
}
}
public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(),"datePicker");
}




}
```

MyBroadcastReceiver.java

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "test");

        //Acquire the lock
        wl.acquire();

        Toast.makeText(context, "Call"+MainActivity.text.getText()+MainActivity.text2.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.i("test", "ALARM!!!");
        showNotification(context);
        Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vibrator.vibrate(2000);

        //Release the lock

        wl.release();
    }
    private void showNotification(Context context) {
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                new Intent(context, MainActivity.class), 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("My notification")
                .setContentText("Call"+MainActivity.text.getText()+MainActivity.text2.getText());
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
    }
    public void setOnetimeTimer(Context context, long when) {
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, when, pi);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the alarm when time selected from timepicker dialog.

update your button click code with

```
 btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) 
{

 DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(),"datePicker");


                }
            });
```

AND ON WHEN TIME SELECTED

```
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    String am_pm = "";

   c= Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);

               timePicked = c.getTimeInMillis();
                    Log.d("test", "timePicked: " + timePicked);
                    Log.d("test", "current: " + System.currentTimeMillis() );
                    if (timePicked != -1) {
                        MyBroadcastReceiver alarm = new MyBroadcastReceiver();
                        if(alarm != null) alarm.setOnetimeTimer(MainActivity.this,timePicked);

                        btn.setText("ALARM SET");
                        Log.d("test", "ALARM SET!!!");
                    } else {
                        //warn the user for ALARM not set?
                        Log.w("test", "ALARM not SET!!!");
                    }
        }
```

you can also cancel your previously set alarm .

Comment: I have taken timePicked as long type variable.Here u r assigning Calendar.getInstance() to it..What type of variable you have taken timePicked as?

Comment: I want alarm to be set when user clicks on button not when time selected from TimePicker dialog..